# Unable to connect to SQL Node MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I have a Management node, 2 Data Node and 2 SQL Node in 2 server. Management in one of the server. Im unable to connect to my SQL Node for some reason that don't know. I thought maybe I did something to the config file(which I did) so I fresh set up a new server for the clustering but still the same result and when I run back the data node, it cannot allocate the id.

Server1 (Mgmt,Data,SQL)
Server2 (Data,SQL)

First time when I start the data node, was ok

```
2017-08-24 10:50:11 [ndbd] INFO     -- Angel connected to '192.168.1.69:1186'                                                         
2017-08-24 10:50:15 [ndbd] INFO     -- Angel allocated nodeid: 2
```

Second try Failed :(

```
2017-08-23 12:25:48 [ndbd] INFO     -- Angel connected to '192.168.1.69:1186'
2017-08-23 12:26:19 [ndbd] ERROR    -- Failed to allocate nodeid, error: 'Error: Could not alloc node id at 192.168.1.69 port 1186: No free node id found for ndbd(NDB).'
```

Here is what shows in the Management Node

```
-- NDB Cluster -- Management Client --
ndb_mgm> show
Connected to Management Server at: 192.168.1.69:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
id=2    @192.168.1.69  (mysql-5.6.28 ndb-7.4.10, Nodegroup: 0, *)
id=3    @192.168.1.70  (mysql-5.6.28 ndb-7.4.10, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @192.168.1.69  (mysql-5.6.28 ndb-7.4.10)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.1.69)
id=5 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.1.70)
```

My config file 
(config.ini)

```
[ndb_mgmd default]
# Directory for MGM node log files
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

[ndb_mgmd]
#Management Node db1
NodeId: 1
HostName=192.168.1.69

[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2      # Number of replicas
DataMemory=256M     # Memory allocate for data storage
IndexMemory=128M    # Memory allocate for index storage
#Directory for Data Node
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

[ndbd]
#Data Node db2
NodeId: 2
HostName=192.168.1.69

[ndbd]
#Data Node db3
NodeId: 3
HostName=192.168.1.70

[mysqld]
#SQL Node db4
NodeId: 4
HostName=192.168.1.69
```

(my.cnf)

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring=192.168.1.69     # IP address of Management Node
default_storage_engine=ndbcluster     # Define default Storage Engine used by MySQL

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=192.168.1.69     # IP address of Management Node
```

Please Help!!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You already have both of your 2 data nodes up and running.
So not sure why you want to start a data node already running.

Seems to me that it is the MySQL Servers you want to start now.